# Screen goes black randomly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server

The screen of a Windows Server 2012 Essentials with version 6.2.920000 randomly turns black and the system seems to be frozen, forcing us to physically reboot the machine.

It happens completely by surprise, not right after login.

By looking into the event visor, everything seems pretty normal.

/sfc scannow and chkdsk return no errors.

ctrl+alt+del won't work while the screen is black.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/a-windows-server-2012-r2-server-becomes-slow-and-unresponsive-if-update-2927901-is-installed-b57c659f-892b-68cb-562c-7d9a83313848) answer your question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: After restarting, do you see any errors in the event viewer which might be related? I have had the same problem when I used an SSD which was not properly connected (and I expect that improperly connected RAM would have a similar effect).

Comment: @Ruben I see the kernel power 41 error which I assume is caused by forcefully powering off the machine. Is this correct?